# Alphanumeric Sort for SortableBindingList

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sorting, datagridview

I have implemented a SortableBindingList for my DataGridView. On one particular column which is a String, I'd like to extend the sort functionality so that it includes alphanumeric sorting. For example, the items 1a,10a,9a would be sorted like this: 1a 9a 10a.

My SortableBindingList is implemented below. Where would I customize this to implement alphanumeric sorting for one particular column?

```
//implement sorting for BindingList so columns can be sorted in datagridview.
    public class SortableBindingList<T>: BindingList<T>
    {
        protected override bool SupportsSortingCore
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        protected override bool IsSortedCore
        {
            get
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count - 1; ++i)
                {
                    T lhs = Items[i];
                    T rhs = Items[i + 1];
                    PropertyDescriptor property = SortPropertyCore;
                    if (property != null)
                    {
                        object lhsValue = lhs == null ? null :
property.GetValue(lhs);
                        object rhsValue = rhs == null ? null :
property.GetValue(rhs);
                        int result;
                        if (lhsValue == null)
                        {
                            result = -1;
                        }
                        else if (rhsValue == null)
                        {
                            result = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result =
Comparer.Default.Compare(lhsValue, rhsValue);
                        }
                        if (SortDirectionCore ==
ListSortDirection.Descending)
                        {
                            result = -result;
                        }
                        if (result >= 0)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

        private ListSortDirection sortDirection;
        protected override ListSortDirection SortDirectionCore
        {
            get
            {
                return sortDirection;
            }
        }


        private PropertyDescriptor sortProperty;
        protected override PropertyDescriptor SortPropertyCore
        {
            get
            {
                return sortProperty;
            }
        }


        protected override void ApplySortCore(PropertyDescriptor prop,
ListSortDirection direction)
        {
            sortProperty = prop;
            sortDirection = direction;

            List<T> list = (List<T>)Items;
            list.Sort(delegate(T lhs, T rhs)
            {
                if (sortProperty != null)
                {
                    object lhsValue = lhs == null ? null :
sortProperty.GetValue(lhs);
                    object rhsValue = rhs == null ? null :
sortProperty.GetValue(rhs);
                    int result;
                    if (lhsValue == null)
                    {
                        result = -1;
                    }
                    else if (rhsValue == null)
                    {
                        result = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = Comparer.Default.Compare(lhsValue,
rhsValue);
                    }
                    if (sortDirection == ListSortDirection.Descending)
                    {
                        result = -result;
                    }
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            });
        }


        protected override void RemoveSortCore()
        {
            sortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
            sortProperty = null;
        } 


    }
```

Comment: `Comparer.Default.Compare(lhsValue, rhsValue);` is the customizable part.

Comment: Maybe pass an `IComparer<T>` or `Comparison<T>` delegate to the constructor and use that instead of `Comparer.Default`.  That way you allow for third-party comparisons, such as alphanumeric.

Comment: Once you have an `IComparer<T>`-based constructor, you could look at http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting for an example of natural sorting